# Deploying ASP.NET Web API to IIS Server

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

I developed my first Web API and am trying to deploy it to my QA server.  I created a website in IIS called qa.mysite.com.  I deployed my Web API to this folder and am trying to run it.

When I debug the site locally and go to

> `http://localhost:3735/api/Bid_Received`

it works correctly.  However, when I go to

> `http://qa.mysite.com/api/Bid_Received`

I get a 404 error.

What am I doing wrong? Did I not upload the correct files?

When I look in my folder that I deployed my web API to I see the following items:

Folders: bin, Content, Images, Scripts, Views
Files: favicon.ico, Global.asax, packages.config, Web.config

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problems.

1. I didn't have .Net 4.0 installed on this server so I installed it.
2. I registered .Net 4.0 with IIS
3. I set this website to use .Net 4.0
4. This box was running IIS6 so I followed the advice in this article to get ASP.Net Web API to work with IIS6 [ASP.Net MVC on IIS6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx)

Comment: did you upload full source on server hosting or you compiled them firs using publish wizard and then uploaded it on hosting server ??